# spring kafka @sendTo runtime expression

Tags: spring-kafka

Any explanation or examples please about the runtime expression of `@SendTo("!{someExpression}")` ?

From documentation:

> @SendTo("!{someExpression}") routes to the topic determined by evaluating the expression
> at runtime.
> The #root object for the evaluation has three properties:
> request: The inbound ConsumerRecord (or ConsumerRecords object for a batch listener))
> source: The org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> converted from the request.
> result: The method return result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed there, there are 3 properties you can use, the consumer record `request`, the converted `Message` named `source` and the result value.

e.g. `request.value().someProperty`, `source.headers['foo']`, `result.someProperty`.

Or you can invoke some bean method with one or more of these properties.

`@someBean.someMethod(request)`.